# equivalent inductance

Tags: inductance

If two circuits 1 and 2, are coupled through the coils of inductance L1 (in circuit 1) and L2 (in circuit 2), how does the inductance value of L2 affect L1 ? and what is the inductance value seen by circuit 1?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAAIiH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic how is L1 affected by L2? or how is Leq calculated?
How is the resonance calculated? when L2 is affecting L1?

Comment: You might want to read about [mutual inductance](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-14/mutual-inductance/).

Comment: i actually have problem in understanding mutual inductance 
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213138/equivalent-inductance?

Comment: L2 has zero effect until current is taken. At the moment you show no load on L2 so the answer to your question is trivial i.e. zero effect.

Comment: I made changes in the circuit and question? hope it is clear

Comment: -1 for not showing ANY effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 1:1 transformer, L1 = L2 and any voltage applied to L1 will appear across L2 at the same amplitude providing the coupling factor (k) is 1. Any load connected to L2 will have no effect - input and output voltage amplitudes will be the same

If the coupling factor is (say) 0.5 and L2 is unloaded, the output voltage (across L2) becomes 50% of input voltage. In effect, a k of 0.5 turns L1 from a coil that was totally coupling L2 to a coil that is only 50% coupled. So, using simple numbers, if L1 is 1 henry it can be regarded as a leakage inductance of 0.5 henries and a coupled inductor of 0.5 henries in series. This forms a potential divider and the coupled inductor part only "sees" 50% of the input voltage and, of course this 50% voltage is seen on the unloaded L2 terminals: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLTkHX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

L2 is also split the same way - 50% of it is coupled to 50% of L1 and there is a leakage inductance of 50%. This leakage inductance has no effect if no current is being drawn from the secondary. So, for coils that are equal but coupled 50% (k = 0.5) the unloaded output voltage is 50% of the input voltage.

Any loading on the secondary becomes in series with 50% of L2. This further changes the output voltage in two ways: -

- 50% of L2 forms a potential divider with the load
- The extra current through the primary leakage inductance further drops the voltage that is coupled.

Without a specific proposal for a load and values of L1 and L2 I'm not going to do a whole load of maths to give a generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the Wikipedia article on [inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) there is a section on [mutual inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Coupled_inductors_and_mutual_inductance) which explains what you are asking.

When there's a mutual inductance present, the voltage across inductor 1 can be found as

$$v_1 = L_1\frac{\text{d}i_1}{\text{d}t} - M\frac{\text{d}i_2}{\text{d}t}$$

(\$L_1\$ is the inductance of inductor #1 and \$M\$ is the mutual inductance)

This means you can't know the effect of the mutual inductance from inductor 2 on the circuit containing inductor 1 until you also know the complete circuit connected to inductor 2 so that you can determine \$i_2(t)\$ and its derivative.

You cannot reduce the effect to an equivalent change in inductance in coil 1 until you know the complete circuit.